# Ignore partial filename only if in specific directory

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

I wish to ignore:

```
settings/local_*.py
apps/settings/local_*.py
path_to/settings/local_*.py
```

But I don't wish to ignore:

```
local_*.py
something/else/local_*.py
```

And also I don't wish to ignore:

```
settings/non_local_*.py
...
```

Is this beyond gitignore?

Of course, I'm looking for a generic solution that will work no matter where the `settings` directory is located (within the repo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, I stabbed at the solution!

`settings/local_*.py` won't work.

But this will: `**/settings/local_*.py`!